# update/insert a random date range with custom year and month - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, random

update/insert a random date range with custom year and month

example :

```
UPDATE `tbl_name` set Date = CONCAT('2014-03-' , [random number not lesser than 1] ,
  [random number not greater than 31] , [RANDOM HOUR] , ':' , [RANDOM MINUTES] , ':'
  , [RANDOM SECONDS] )
```

is this possible not using stored procedure?

thanks,
Dave

Comment: Why would you need a sproc for this? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot determine the random date in your application layer where undoubtedly your programming language of choice has better facilities for doing this?

Comment: im just new to the database, and im maintaining it, and the client does not have the idea how it gone through like this, i think they were hacked or something. so i did lots of trial and errors in mysql here  to edit the dates that are erroneous but there are 1k+ rows so i need some mysql update to do that for me. Ive tried other trials to only 1 record but failed in doing so. im still finding other solution in the internet.

Comment: @MarcB oh god, im stupid... it does work using that, im stupid and confused lol. but thanks i did it.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for doc* I was looking at it lately but i dont know where to look. and thanks to Rossm you helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the MySQL RAND() function to generate a random number. Look at the following example:

```
FLOOR(7 + (RAND() * 5))
```

As Mike mentioned, this seems to be logic that would belong in the application layer.

Comment: thanks bro, I was confused at that time. thanks to all who helped.